# Doctrine Symfony Query Many to Many Issue : Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship

**My goal is to get all the application by influencer Id.** 
I tried that :

```
public function findApplicationByInfluencer($value): ?Application
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('a.influencerId = :value')
        ->setParameter('value', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }
```

But get this error: "**[Semantical Error] line 0, col 47 near 'influencerId': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.**"

Which I don't understand and don't know how to fix it.
I have delete some code from the entities which doesn't affect my question.

#### Application Entity  :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ApplicationRepository::class)
 */
class Application
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Influencer::class, inversedBy="applications")
     */
    private $influencerId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->influencerId = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Influencer[]
     */
    public function getInfluencerId(): Collection
    {
        return $this->influencerId;
    }

    public function addInfluencerId(Influencer $influencerId): self
    {
        if (!$this->influencerId->contains($influencerId)) {
            $this->influencerId[] = $influencerId;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeInfluencerId(Influencer $influencerId): self
    {
        $this->influencerId->removeElement($influencerId);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

#### Influencer Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InfluencerRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("username", message="Ce pseudo est déjà utilisé")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Influencer
{
    const SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER = '/public/uploads';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Application::class, mappedBy="influencerId")
     */
    private $applications;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applications = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->brandId = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * @return Collection|Application[]
     */
    public function getApplications(): Collection
    {
        return $this->applications;
    }

    public function addApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if (!$this->applications->contains($application)) {
            $this->applications[] = $application;
            $application->addInfluencerId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeApplication(Application $application): self
    {
        if ($this->applications->removeElement($application)) {
            $application->removeInfluencerId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be more semantically correct to rename the field and related methods from `influencerId` to `influencers`.

You have a ManyToMany relation, that means you need to check if the `Influencer` is `in` the `ArrayCollection`.

```
->where(':value in a.influencerId')
```

However, you should not need to run that query as that result is already returned by the `Influencer:getApplications` method. So, that means you can do the following directly in your controller:

1. If you have the `Influencer` entity:

```
/** @var Collection|Application[] $Applications */
$Applications = $influencer->getApplications();
```

2. If you have only the `Influencer:id` value:

```
/** @var Collection|Application[] $Applications */
$Applications = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Influencer::class)->find($influencer_id)->getApplications();
```

Comment: Okay thank you ! I will change the entity too